# Format of microphone audio passed to call back in mac OS X core audio example

Tags: macos, core-audio

I need access to audio data from microphone on macbook.  I have the an example program for recording microphone data based on the one in "Learning Core Audio".  When I run this program and break on the call back routine I see the inBuffer pointer and the mAudioData pointer.  However I am having a heck of a time making sense of the data. I've tried casting the void* pointer to mAudioData to SInt16, to SInt32 and to float and tried a number of endian conversions all with nonsense looking results.  What I need to know definitively is the number format for the data in the buffer.  The example actually works writing microphone data to a file which I can play so I know that real audio is being recorded.

```
   AudioStreamBasicDescription recordFormat;
memset(&recordFormat,0,sizeof(recordFormat));
//recordFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC;
recordFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
recordFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;
recordFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
recordFormat.mBytesPerPacket = recordFormat.mBytesPerFrame = recordFormat.mChannelsPerFrame * sizeof(SInt16);
recordFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
MyGetDefaultInputDeviceSampleRate(&recordFormat.mSampleRate);
UInt32 propSize = sizeof(recordFormat);
CheckError(AudioFormatGetProperty(kAudioFormatProperty_FormatInfo,
                                  0,
                                  NULL,
                                  &propSize,
                                  &recordFormat),
           "AudioFormatProperty failed");

//set up queue
AudioQueueRef queue = {0};
CheckError(AudioQueueNewInput(&recordFormat,
                              MyAQInputCallback,
                              &recorder,
                              NULL,
                              kCFRunLoopCommonModes,
                              0,
                              &queue),
           "AudioQueueNewInput failed");
UInt32 size = sizeof(recordFormat);
CheckError(AudioQueueGetProperty(queue,
                                 kAudioConverterCurrentOutputStreamDescription,
                                 &recordFormat,
                                 &size), "Couldn't get queue's format");
```

Comment: Can you show your audio callback code and the audio setup code?

Comment: Thanks for response.  Here is my call back function and main.

Comment: Here is main.c and call back function listings.

Comment: How do I show my code?  Comments are too limited to paste here.

Comment: You can link to a gist

Comment: I've never used github or gist so don't know how to proceed.  Can you help?

Comment: Either paste the relevant code into this question, or sign up for github and click the "gist" button, then add the link it gives you to your question.

Comment: AudioStreamBasicDescription recordFormat;
    memset(&recordFormat,0,sizeof(recordFormat));
    recordFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    recordFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;
    recordFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
    recordFormat.mBytesPerPacket = recordFormat.mBytesPerFrame = recordFormat.mChannelsPerFrame * sizeof(SInt16);
    recordFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
    MyGetDefaultInputDeviceSampleRate(&recordFormat.mSampleRate);
    UInt32 propSize = sizeof(recordFormat);

Comment: Previous comment shows some of the setup of the ASBD structure I use to setup new queue.  When called it spits out this

Comment: 2015-11-29 23:36:14.338 MyAudio[1859:609293] 23:36:14.336 ERROR:    >aq> 327: AudioConverterNew from AudioQueueNew returned 'fmt?'
io:     2 ch,  44100 Hz, Float32, non-inter
client:    2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000000) 16-bit little-endian unsigned integer

Comment: in the Xcode debugger console.

Comment: it sounds like your audio is 2 channels of audio, each one is a 44.1khz stream of floats? so try interpreting them as floats rather than ints...

Comment: That is correct.  My mistake was setting the formatID to kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC (commented out in the code shown).  Found that I had to in addition specify mFormatFlags to kAudioFormatFlagsCanonical.  Now when I interpret the data as float looks reasonable.